# I want to react usestate or other hooks. Implement a 60 second countdown. How

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my attempt to implement a counter.

```
const [stateTime, setTime] = useState(time);

let countDown = () => { 
  setTime(stateTime - 1);
};

let intervalTimer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(intervalTimer);
}, 5000);
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, what would you like to do? there's a lot of articles already about hooks that have plenty of information to help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```js
const CountDown = ({ seconds }) => {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    // exit early when we reach 0
    if (!timeLeft) return;

    // save intervalId to clear the interval when the
    // component re-renders
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft(timeLeft - 1);
    }, 1000);

    // clear interval on re-render to avoid memory leaks
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    // add timeLeft as a dependency to re-rerun the effect
    // when we update it
  }, [timeLeft]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timeLeft}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In your parent component

```
<CountDown seconds={60} />
```

Comment: Very Good， Thanks ❤️